# PHP Array traversing foreach loop[?

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => LinkedIn Corporation
    [1] => www.linkedin.com
    [2] => 2029 Stierlin Ct
Mountain View, CA 94043-4655
United States  map
    [3] => +1.650.687.3600
    [4] => Software & Internet, E-commerce and Internet Businesses
Software & Internet, Data Analytics, Management and Storage
Business Services, HR and Recruiting Services
    [5] => 1K - 10K
    [6] => > $1B
    [7] => Publicly Traded - NASDAQ : LNKD
)
```

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 2):

By the way `foreach` is not a loop but a language construct.

Traverse like this.

```
foreach($yourarr as $k=>$v)
{
echo "The Key:$k and The Value:$v<br>";
}
```